mlr3: How to extract predicted survival time? (to compare the model predictions with the real data)
I want to predict the response of predicted survival times in survival analysis. According to the book mlr3 for comparing the predictions from the model to the true data (https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/chapters/chapter13/beyond_regression_and_classification.html#learnersurv-predictionsurv-and-predict-types).
In the below, I'm training and predicting survival from an xgboost (lrn("surv.xgboost.cox")), and I've used type = "regression" for survival time prediction.
But It seems that the argument 'type' is not a valid argument for Learner 'Surv.Xgboost.Cox'.
**How can I compare the predicted survival times from the model to the true survival times data?
**
library(mlr3proba)
#> Loading required package: mlr3

library(mlr3extralearners)
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3verse)
task = as_task_surv(x = survival::veteran, time = 'time', event = 'status')
poe = po('encode')
task = poe$train(list(task))[[1]]
set.seed(42)
part = partition(task, ratio = 0.8)
pred_xgb = lrn("surv.xgboost.cox", type = "regression")$
  train(task, split$train)$predict(task, split$test)
#> Error: Cannot set argument 'type' for 'LearnerSurvXgboostCox' (not a constructor argument, not a parameter, not a field. Did you mean 'normalize_type' / 'process_type' / 'sample_type'?

data.frame(pred = pred_xgb$response[1:3],
           truth = pred_xgb$truth[1:3])
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'pred_xgb' not found

Created on 2024-05-24 with reprex v2.1.0

Not sure where you're getting "regression" from -- this is not a valid type. The valid prediction types are listed in the chapter you link to. You want "response" for this one.

In addition to johns answer. It's quite unusual in survival context to predcit actual survival time because of the presence of censoring, especially for non-/semi-parametric methods like Cox. Usually you instead estimate the (improper) distribution, e.g. the survival probability and then compare at different timepoints the "alive" status with the predicted probabilities. Even median might not be defined, if censoring percentage is high. When you use parametric models, prediction of event times is possible, however, you often run risk of extrapolation.

The prediction types of the surv.xgboost.cox are documented clearly in the respective doc page.
To get the response prediction for this learner you have to use the crankcompositor, see example here - you will need to change to method = median to get true survival times though. I will soon add a new method to estimate the response as the RMST which would give more sensible survival times. I have created an issue here.
Lastly, there are measures in mlr3proba that use the response (survival time) as input, such as msr("surv.mae") and msr("surv.rmse").
BR, John.
